# How to clear the text field in formsy material ui React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, formsy-material-ui, formsy-react

Hi I am using React 14 and writing it in ES6. I am using formsy-material-ui  for form validations. There is a scenario where I want to clear the value of text field on click of a button.

I tried the following code

```
<FormsyText
    name="email"
    ref="email"
    validations="isEmail"
    validationError="Invalid Email"
    hintText="Email"
    value={this.state.emailValue}
/>
```

And on click of the button, I am executing the following line of code

```
this.setState({emailValue : ''});
```

But the text field is not getting cleared. 
How to clear it.
Pls help.

Comment: Is the button component being rendered inside the same component as the <FormsyText> component? Are you using a store hold state?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, if you were using a controlled input (maybe using directly the `TextField` from Material-ui) - your code would be right, however the `FormsyText` component handle it's value internally.
If you pass a `value` or `defaultValue` it'll just be used when it's rendered, you can check it [here](https://github.com/mbrookes/formsy-material-ui/blob/master/src/FormsyText.jsx#L21).

I only see one way to clear the value now, in an imperative style.

```
this.refs.email.setState({ value: "" })
```

Note: I suggest you to change the way you're using the `ref`. Using refs with a string is deprecated and probably will be removed in the future. Instead you should pass a function that's gonna receive that component.   https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html
Example:

```
<FormsyText
    name="email"
    ref={(node) => this._emailText = node}
    validations="isEmail"
    validationError="Invalid Email"
    hintText="Email"
    value={this.state.emailValue}
/>
//And to clear it
this._emailText.setState({ value: "" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try reset field after setState:

```
this.setState({emailValue : ''});
this.refs.email.reset()
```

Also you can reset all form.

```
this.refs.form.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const formRefdeposit = useRef(null);

<Formsy
        onValidSubmit={handleSubmit}
        onValid={enableButton}
        onInvalid={disableButton}
        ref={formRef}
 >
....Form Fields
</Formsy>
```

if you have class in your js file then use

```
this.formRef.current.reset();
```

if without class then use

```
formRef.current.reset();
```